# Replace string with another string based on backreference with sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I'm trying to convert a predefined string `%c#` where `#` can be some number with another string. The catch is that the length of the other string must be truncated to `#` number of characters.

Ideally these set of commands would work:

```
FORMAT="%c10"
LAST_COMMIT="5189e42b14797b1e36ffb7fc5657c7eea08f1c0f"
echo $FORMAT | sed "s/%c\([0-9]\+\)/${LAST_COMMIT:0:\1}/g"
```

but clearly there is a syntax error on the \1. You can replace it with a number to see what I'm trying to get as output.

I'm open to using some other program other than `sed` to achieve this but ideally it should be programs that are pretty much native to most linux installations.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can change your format string's format, then `printf` can be an option `printf "%.10s" "5189e42b14797b1e36ffb7fc5657c7eea08f1c0f"`

Comment: Are you trying to write a pretty git-log output?

Comment: Yep. And ok interesting idea. I can do it in two steps. 1. Replace %c# to %.#s then do the replace. Can anyone else figure out how to do it in one-ish step?

Comment: @nhahtdh Can't seem to get your solution to work with multiple substitutions i.e. pass multiple number of arguments to printf dynamically. Help? :)

Comment: It works fine for me `printf "%.10s %.10s" "5189e42b14797b1e36ffb7fc5657c7eea08f1c0f" "abcdef5189e42b14797b1e36ffb7fc5657c7eea08f1c0f"` outputs `5189e42b14 abcdef5189`. I'm not entirely sure about platform difference, though.

Comment: Correct. It WILL work fine. That's not the problem. The problem is how to pass the LAST_COMMIT multiple times to printf in the bash script. I could have 5 %c's and then it shold pass LAST_COMMIT as 5 string arguments to printf dynamically.

Comment: @Sanchit You need to write your own code to figure out the number of arguments and pass them in accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my idea.

```
echo ${LAST_COMMIT} | head -c $(echo ${FORMAT} | sed -e 's/%c//')
```

Get number with `sed` and get first some character with `head`.

**EDIT1**

This might be better.

```
echo ${LAST_COMMIT} | head -c $(echo ${FORMAT} | sed -e 's/%c\([0-9]\+\)/\1/')
```

**EDIT2**

I make the script because it is too tough to understand. Please try this.

```
$ cat sample.sh

#!/bin/bash

FORMAT="%b-%t-%c10-%c5"
LAST_COMMIT="5189e42b14797b1e36ffb7fc5657c7eea08f1c0f"

## List numbers
lengths=$(echo ${FORMAT} | sed -e "s/%[^c]//g" -e "s/-//g" -e "s/%c/ /g")

## Substitute %cXX to first XX characters of LAST_COMMIT
for n in ${lengths}
do
  to_str=$(echo ${LAST_COMMIT:0:${n}})
  FORMAT=$(echo ${FORMAT} | sed "s/%c${length}/${to_str}/")
done

## Print result
echo ${FORMAT}
```

This is the result.

```
$ ./sample.sh
%b-%t-5189e42b1410-5189e5
```

Also this is one line commands (Same contents but too long and too tough)

```
for n in $(echo ${FORMAT} | sed -e "s/%[^c]//g" -e "s/-//g" -e "s/%c/ /g"); do to_str=$(echo ${LAST_COMMIT:0:${n}}); FORMAT=$(echo ${FORMAT} | sed "s/%c${length}/${to_str}/"); done; echo ${FORMAT}
```

Comment: Just to be clear. Will this replace all occurrences of `%c#` or just the first one? All is not a requirement but is preferred.

Comment: "s/%c//" will remove only first "%c". So, 's/%c\([0-9]\+\)/\1/' might be better. I edit my answer

Comment: Note that format will be a lot of stuff. `FORMAT="%b-%t-%c10-%c5"` perhaps. Everything else will be taken care of and eventually you'll be left with a string with only `%c#`'s

Comment: Which %c# do you need? `echo ${FORMAT} | sed -e 's/^.*%c\([0-9]\+\)-%c\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1/g'` will return first number of %c# (i.e. return 10). And `echo ${FORMAT} | sed -e 's/^.*%c\([0-9]\+\)-%c\([0-9]\+\).*$/\2/g'` will return second number of %c# (i.e. return 5).

Comment: My question is different. Given `LAST_COMMIT="asdfghjkl"` and `FORMAT="%c2-%c5"` The code should return `as-asdfg`. Doesn't have to be one line.

Comment: Thanks your more info and sample result. I update my answer. Pls check my EDIT2

Answer (score 0):

```
length=$(echo $FORMAT | sed "s/%c\([0-9]\+\)/\1/g")
echo "${LAST_COMMIT:0:$length}"
```

Comment: You have a syntax error -- there is a significant difference between `$(...)` and `${...}`.  Also, you should not use `echo` without proper quoting, in general.  Finally, all of this can be simplified to `echo "${LAST_COMMIT:0:${FORMAT/%c/}}"` as long as the format string is just a single format specifier, as you are already assuming anyway.

Comment: @tripleee yes you are right, I actually run that command with { } but typed here in round brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$LAST_COMMIT` gets interpolated before `sed` runs, so there is no backreference to refer back to yet.  There is an `/e` extension in GNU `sed` which would support something like this, but I would simply use a slightly more capable tool.

```
perl -e '$fmt = shift; $fmt=~ s/%c(\d+)/%.$1s/g; printf("$fmt\n", @ARGV)' '%c10' "$LAST_COMMIT"
```

Of course, if you can let go of your own ad-hoc format string specifier, and switch to a `printf`-compatible format string altogether, just use the `printf` shell command straight off.